# how to remove "resource not found error in servlet"?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

```
<html>

<body>

<table border="1" align="center" style="width:50%;height: 50%;border-bottom-   style: solid;border-bottom-width: thick;">
<tr>
    <td align="center" ><h2>welcome user</h2>

     <form method="post" action="Register">
    <input type="submit" value="view full list" />
    </form>
    </td>

</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i have created a servlet Register and in my jsp page. I have called that register servlet....when I click view full list but I  am getting an error **http404 resource not found**(only when clicked on view all list)

Comment: When you click, you are sending a request to `/Register` and it would seem that you do not have anything which can handle requests to that URL.

Comment: if you are trying to submit the form to the Regsiter.jsp, then you need to specify Register.jsp in action attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="Register.jsp">
```

Comment: A register servlet is mentioned.

Comment: register is a servlet